# How do I get on a Minecraft PE server that says it is full but it is not?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a Minecraft PE server for my friends and I, but whenever I use my IP address, it says that the server is full but it's not. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the app, then redownloading it, but I don't recommend doing this unless you don't have any good worlds you want to keep. (Alternatively you could make a backup so you don't lost them.) Try removing the server, then adding it back. Also try waiting for a while until the server player count goes down. If none of that works, you could change your WiFi/Ethernet or any internet IP address. If none of the above works, contact apple support or whatsoever support, contact Mojang, or ask the admin of the server.

I have never ran across this error, so I am just suggesting.